# How to convert these from the given free energy $G$ vs $X$ to $T$ vs $X$ diagrams?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, phase-diagram

[image]

What I really do not understand is how they are converting from G vs X curves to T vs X. I have a couple of more diagrams with which I am having problems. A detailed answer to this is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, binary phase diagrams (not to mention ternary) are a bit difficult to 'get' when you first encounter them. While I dearly love Porter and Easterling's book, this figure is not the best presentation.

First, the final diagram, (f), should really be considered as a map, not curves. If you look at the map of a country, the cities and roads are not functions of North-South vs East-West - they just exist in those particular places. Similarly in (f), the purpose is to be able to look at a particular temperature and composition and be able to determine what the stable phase or combination of phases is at that point. These are the regions to the left of $b$ and right of $c$ compositions. Between points $b$ and $c$ on the composition axis, you have a tie line indicating that the lowest free energy of the system is a mix of the solid and the liquid. The precise mix depends on the composition linearly across the tie line.

Now, how to determine what phases are stable where? For that one turns to the Gibbs free energies of possible phases, determine which phase or combination of phases has the lowest total Gibbs free energy. Plots (a) through (e) are doing just that - at a given temperature what are the Gibbs free energy curves of the solid and liquid plotted vs relative concentration.

In (a) the temperature is above the melting point of both elements and the Gibbs free energy of the liquid is below that of the solid everywhere. The only stable phase is the liquid. If you look on (f), at that temperature, you are in the 'liquid' phase area all the way across the composition range.

Similarly for (e), the temperature is below the melting point of both elements, and the Gibbs free energy of the solid is below that of the liquid everywhere, so the only stable phase is the solid.

(b) and (d) are interesting only in the fact that they are the melting temperatures of the pure elements, so the Gibbs free energy of the pure solid and the pure liquid (for A and B in (b) and (d) respectively) are equal. That is shown by the solid and liquid curves touching at those pure melting points.

(c) is the more difficult one to understand. At a given temperature between (b) and (d), you have one pure element as a solid and one pure element as a liquid. What happens in between? For some compositions only the solid exists, for others only the liquid. These regions are to the left of composition $b$ and the right of composition $c$.

In between those points is the tie line between the liquid and the solid. This represents the lowest free energy that the system can attain using a combination of liquid and solid phases, the relative amounts of which change linearly between $b$ and $c$. This is your two phase region.

So, going back to the map analogy for diagram (f), color in the top portion blue (for liquid water). Color in the bottom portion green (for solid land). Then the middle lozenge-shaped (Mentos-shaped?) region is yellow (for the beach where solid meets liquid). Now you have a map of what phases (solid, liquid, solid+liquid) are present where on the range of temperature and composition conditions.

As a last point, this is a fairly simple diagram, with complete solubilities in both the liquid and the solid, as well as no enthalpy of mixing contribution. This is actually close to several real phase diagrams. As an example, the plot below is a calculation for the Si-Ge phase diagram, using free-energy expressions given in the reference on the plot. The bottom panel is the phase diagram, the top panel is the last (highest temperature) set of free energy curves for the solid and liquid.

[image: Si-Ge phase diagram]