# How to get a vs X from G vs X?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, material-science

Typically for this diagram(also taken from the book Porter and Easterling) I really do not understand how is activity of A vs mole fraction of A been derived.I really do not understand how they plotted a vs X for the given G vs X situation.A detailed reply to this will be most welcome.

[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616608/2451

Comment: Relate G to chemical potential to A...

Comment: @JonCuster I did relate and even found out a relation.However what I really do not understand is how are the straight lines for the curves being drawn while plotting the activites.I am getting an exponential relation.How does that modify to a straight line?I hope you get the point.Secondly,for the region $\alpha_{e}$ to $\beta_{e}$ which straight line to consider?(The one above or the one below).The thinking analogy for even a single segment will be appreciated.

Comment: How does G of the mixture change with a small change in composition. How is that expressed using chemical potential? It’s right there in Porter and Easterling.